# Add Flask-WSGI routes to DDEV-Drupal project

Tags: docker, flask, wsgi, ddev

I have a ddev-Drupal project and want to add web-routing for my python-flask project. Ideally something like this: https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/flask-redis - or maybe with gunicorn? In the end i want the flask-app to run at http:myproject.ddev.site:5000 or similar...

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use two projects, one for your Drupal PHP project, and the other for your flask project.

They can easily communicate with each other as described in the [FAQ](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/faq/#can-different-projects-communicate-with-each-other)

The Drupal project is just standard, easy setup, per the [quickstart docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#drupal).

Your Flask project can also be set up using the [quickstart docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#pythonflask-experimental)

Now wire them together and it should be OK. Come on by the [DDEV Discord](https://discord.gg/5wjP76mBJD) if you need more interactive help. This is an unusual configuration!

Edit: I'm not sure why you'd be using flask for Redis. Have you checked out the `ddev-redis` add-on? https://github.com/ddev/ddev-redis

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Re: redis, my apologies that was a bad example. Actually we use Qdrant, and we have a working `docker-compose.qdrant.yaml` already - it works very nicely!

I'm also leaning towards keeping the python-flask in a separate project, but I'm having issues with the ddev python quickstart - the health-check times out waiting for the web container, which never successfully loads... thanks for your invitation, i'll bring this to the Discord channel!

Comment: Python + gunicorn can be tricky because the settings have to be right or it fails on startup. I should be able to help you with this in Discord, especially if you have a simple project I can use to recreate the issue.